# How do I keyframe a shader node?

Tags: animation, shaders, keyframes

I want to keyframe this value to change, how might I do that?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> on the Fac field and pick *[Insert Keyframe](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/keyframes/editing.html#insert-keyframe)*, or hover your mouse over the property you wish to add a keyframe to and press <kbd>I</kbd>.

Comment: Or move the mouse over it and press the I key.